# How to build AutoMapper mapping to pass parameter in destination class constructor

Tags: automapper

What if I have this set of source classes:

```
namespace Source {

    class CA
    {
        public CB B { get; set; }
    }

    class CB {}

}
```

The only difference in destination set of classes is that CB accepts CA reference in constructor (CA is of the same structure):

```
namespace Destination {

    class CA
    {
       public CB B { get; set; }
    }

    class CB
    {
       public CB(CA parent) { ... }
    }
}
```

How can I build a static mapping with AutoMapper for such classes? I mean something that runs once for whole application, not per CA, CB instances.

I know I can do it dynamically like this before every mapping having instance of CA destination:

```
var config = new ConfigurationStore(new TypeMapFactory(), MapperRegistry.Mappers);

config.CreateMap<Source.CB, Destination.CB>()
        .ConstructUsing((ResolutionContext cntx) => 
            new Destination.CB(instanceOfCADestination));
```

but this does not work for me due to performance concerns.

Comment: Your code suggests to me there may be possible improvements in your class hierarchy to begin with. If not, this doesn't really seem like a case for automapper to solve...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found no better way other than instantiating CA before mapping, storing it into IMappingOperationOptions.Options.Items collection and picking it up inside ConstructUsing

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source.CB, Destination.CB>()
      .ConstructUsing(cntx => 
              new Destination.CB((Destination.CA)cntx.Options.Items["CADestRef]));

var destCAInstance = new Destination.CA();

var destCBInstance = 
       Mapper.Map<Destination.CB>(Source.CB, 
                                  opts => opts.Items["CADestRef"] = destCAInstance);
```

This way I can leave whole mapping static. 
Personally I do not like this solution, but it works. Still if you klnow better one please let me know.